# Check if string contains colon or its empty string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

This is the result I am trying to achieve:

`If the "settlementDesc" in messages, has a string without ":" or " ", omit that entry of messages. If all entries are omitted in the messages, then remove the messages entry from the drug price response.`

In code below it's doing opposite operation, any idea what is implemented wrong?

main.js

```
    const messages = [
                  {
                    "settlementCode": "99",
                    "settlementDesc": "Not Covered: Call beneficios."
                },
                   {
                    "settlementCode": "85",
                    "settlementDesc": ""
                },
                  {
                    "settlementCode": "65",
                    "settlementDesc": ":"
                }
                ];

        function validateEntries (messages) {
          if(!messages){ return [] };
          const filteredMsg = messages.filter(mesg => {
            if (checkString(mesg)) return mesg
          } );

          return filteredMsg;
        };

        const checkString = (mesg) => {
          if (mesg.settlementDesc.indexOf(":") || mesg.settlementDesc.indexOf("")) {
            return false;
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        };


    validateEntries(messages);
```

This is the output I am trying to get:

```
  [
    {
        "settlementCode": "99",
        "settlementDesc": "Not Covered: Call beneficios."
    }
  ]
```

Comment: The thing with `settlementDesc.indexOf(":")` is that it will return `0` for `":"`, which may not be what you want. However, your first item in the array has both `:` and ` ` characters, so I'm not sure how you're expecting it to be the only item one remaining in the result array.

Comment: If it is equal to "" or ":" or just if the string has ":"?

Comment: @Jalil f the "settlementDesc" in messages, has a string without ":"  need to omit that entry

Comment: In that case you should be getting 65 too, am I right?

Comment: yes only 85 should be omitted

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you want but:

One way to make a string into an array, or filter it is by doing this:

```
var myString = 'a b c';
console.log(myString.split(' '));
```

This will log an array of `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Trying using includes instead of indexOf as indexOf returns always a number.

```js
const messages = [
              {
                "settlementCode": "99",
                "settlementDesc": "Not Covered: Call beneficios."
            },
               {
                "settlementCode": "85",
                "settlementDesc": ""
            },
              {
                "settlementCode": "65",
                "settlementDesc": ":"
            }
            ];

    function validateEntries (messages) {
      if(!messages){ return [] };
      const filteredMsg = messages.filter(mesg => {
        if (checkString(mesg))  return mesg;
      } );

      return filteredMsg;
    };

    const checkString = (mesg) => {
      if (mesg.settlementDesc.includes(":")) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    };


var output = validateEntries(messages);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Now u can run it and see this is want you wanted.

Comment: Only 99 and 65 should be there right, you can check now by running above code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your list of message and return only wanted ones

```
 const messages = [
                  {
                    "settlementCode": "99",
                    "settlementDesc": "Not Covered: Call beneficios."
                },
                   {
                    "settlementCode": "85",
                    "settlementDesc": ""
                },
                  {
                    "settlementCode": "65",
                    "settlementDesc": ":"
                }
                ];

let filtered = messages.filter(item => item.settlementDesc.includes(":"))
```

Comment: my logic is if string settlementDesc has string without ":" then omit that entry, your logic will remove the entry if string contains ":" right

Comment: If `settlementDesc`  has a string without ":" the `message` will not be in the new array `filtered`

Comment: now above code retruning 85 it should return 99 and 65

Comment: Ok, you can inverse the condition. see my updated code now